# How do I fix NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in iPhone 3.0 OS

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to update my iPhone app to work with OS 3.0.  I have a UIWebView that shows a page fine.  But when I click a link it calls my delegate for didFailLoadWithError and the error is Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)  I verified this is still working with OS 2.2.1, so it is something changed in 3.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: details like which page are in the UIWebView (if it's public) and how you setup this view and delegate in code might be useful.

Comment: I am on the road now and will get more details added when I get back.  It is a public web page.  

In further digging it looks like it may be related to a page not being fully loaded before the next request is received.  I have not had a chance to test that yet.  If that proves to be the issue I will update.

Comment: I think you need to revisit which is considered the correct answer

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I was able to find the answer [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6280-uiwebview-didfailloadwitherror-how-get-errors-code-list.html).

This thread contained this description for this error: `This error may occur if an another request is made before the previous request of WebView is completed...`

I worked around this by ignoring this error and letting the webview continue to load.

```
if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) {
//show error alert, etc.
}
```

Comment: Better to use the constant NSURLErrorCancelled instead of the literal value -999.

Comment: This error may also be a code smell. I got rid of it not by ignoring it, but by moving a load-triggering method call from `viewDidAppear` (which could trigger multiple times while loading the web view) into `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Better yet, the uiwebview has a boolean "loading" property that you should check and then explicitly stop the loading operation.  However, in my case this seems to be the result of deallocating the webview.

Comment: I got rid of it by forcing to reload the url a few times by putting the request in the delegate method - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error. This helps for Twitter and Facebook annoyances

Comment: Man, I owe you a beer

Answer (score 29):

NSURLErrorCancelled (-999)

"Returned when an asynchronous load is canceled. A Web Kit framework delegate will receive this error when it performs a cancel operation on a loading resource. Note that an NSURLConnection or NSURLDownload delegate will not receive this error if the download is canceled."

For my situation (and probably yours) this can be ignored:

```
if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) return; // Ignore this error
```

Answer (score 12):

The above TWO replies was CORRECT>
Just do a return if the loading request causes cancellation.

Also I want to point out that, people **do NOT forget to put an NSLog** inside your **didFailLoadWithError** method, this can prevent losing a lot of time by spotting the issue right on!

So here is the final solution with all I mentioned above:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",error); //Get informed of the error FIRST
    if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) 
        return;
}
```