# web view not able to load specific URL(web kit error domain 102)

Tags: ios, webview, webkit

web view is not able to load URL(www.example.com/index.html?jsonFooter=hideHeaderFooter) i am provoding..this URL works fine in web browser..after a long time digging into this issue, i observe that using web view delegate method for finding error i observed web kit error domain 102..can someone tell me how to solve this issue? thanks in advance..following is my sample code

```
[linkWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/index.html?jsonFooter=hideHeaderFooter",urlStr]]]]
```

Comment: have you checked, the url working in browser..?

Comment: ya..works fine in browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959307/the-joys-of-didfailloadwitherror-uiwebview have a look on this answer, not getting into the issue you are telling.

Comment: i got it..but not able to get any solution for it

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, but this fixed it.
Check if your link is https or http. Incase of http, you will need to update the info plist -> app transport security settings -> allow arbitrary loads in web content -> YES

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType` is returning NO (false).

Ensure this is returning yes.

Comment: it is returning false..but setting it to YES also not solving the issue

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting **WebKitErrorDomain** appears and code is **102** -- It means that webkit can not show page for now at this moment, Its because there may be too many sub-requests and you have to wait a little more.