# NSURLErrorDomain -999 breaks Flash

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I have a `WebView` which works great except in one instance. When it loads a page with a SWF that loads another SWF, the load delegate gets `"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"`

From what I gather, this error happens when a second request is made before the first has completed ([1](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6280-uiwebview-didfailloadwitherror-how-get-errors-code-list.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221079/sending-loadrequest-messages-to-uiwebview-before-current-view-is-finished-loading), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os), [4](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9210463&tstart=0)). I am not expressly doing so, but the SWF is indeed making another request.

Ignoring the error is not a solution--I'm essentially ignoring it as is, and the entire page loads fine except for the Flash content. What can I do to make Flash work?

Comment: You are aware that the iOS doesn't support Flash right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if not implementing the delegate call is the same as ignoring it; WebKit might be trying to handle the error under the hood and causing problems.

In my WebKit/Flash application, I have this in my WebFrameLoadDelegate:

```
- (void) webView:(WebView*)sender 
         didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:(NSError*)error 
         forFrame:(WebFrame*)frame 
{   
    // If the user clicks a link while something is loading this error will
    // be reported. It can be safely ignored (NSURLErrorCancelled -999)
    if ([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) return;

    // Real error handling here...
}
```

And everything works fine. If I take this out I start getting weird failures and even crashes when Flash content is displayed.