# didFailLoadWithError is called with UIWebView even though page later loads

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController which is a UIWebViewDelegate and has a UIWebView inside of it. I am trying to load a particular URL

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView release];
```

But the `didFailLoadWithError`delegate method is almost instantly called, and the error object is:

```
Did fail load with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1a66c0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=www.somewebsite.com, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=www.somewebsite.com}
```

However a short time after, you can see that the website loads just fine.

Why is the fail method being called? And how do I know when it has actually failed versus when the method was called regardless of if the website actually failed or not?

Comment: I got same error because first time I was use url and second time I load url1. Maybe it will help to anyone.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get this error when the page is instantly redirected via javascript or somehow else

You can avoid showing the error by answer from here: [How do I fix NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in iPhone 3.0 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os)

like

```
if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) { //show error alert, etc. }
```

but I don't know how to recognize where it was invoked.

Comment: `if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) { //show error alert, etc. }' URL should be all caps :)

Answer (score 0):

So according to another [StackOverflow question from a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os), the error code you're getting is being caused by a request being made before the previous request has been completed.

What may be happening is you are making multiple calls at the same time / very rapidly, and one is succeeding (so your web page loads) but the other is failing.

Answer (score -1):

Use TapGesture on the web view using tapcount of 1.
Using a function for handling TapGesture, check if the URL returns status code of 200, if so, call the below function

```
-(void)animateme{
    NSString *urlAddress = Connecting_URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

And, using delegate function,

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device in offline" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question