# UIWebView keep loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I can load this link on any web browser http://pentharine.com/fb-inspiration-show.html but when i try to load on UIWebView it's keep loading and throwing error in delegate method. Using  iOS6. I have found this bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/464805153548428 but not sure it is the same thing happening for me since I'm not using 
**fb:comments** plugin in my HTML.

`- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`

error looks like this

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1f5a7de0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://m.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=209286459119433&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df395f1a37c%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F...

Comment: This error is usually showed when the page has some redirect in javascript. Check this answer for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028383/didfailloadwitherror-is-called-with-uiwebview-even-though-page-later-loads

Comment: Thanks Marco, I can avoid the error but still can't load the site.

Comment: Based on what I read, this may be a limitation of the UIWebView component, that avoid redirect in javascript. 
I think the only solution you can follow is to implement the behaviour using the Facebook SDK in iOS or using the new SOcial Framework of iOS 6.

Comment: Yeah! using Facebook SDK is last choice here. Thanks Again :)