# Error Domain=com.flickr Code=108 "The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, flickr

I share image image to *Flickr* using theirs standart [API](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr).

There are no problems with internet, sometimes it uploads the image, sometimes I receive such error.( When i press autorize button)

Can some help to solve or explain this problem? Is it connected with API, my sharing code, internet, or something else? Thank you.

> Error Domain=com.flickr Code=108 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid frob" UserInfo=0x1fdf10e0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Invalid frob}

```
OFFlickrAPIRequest *request = ....;
...
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
NSInputStream *imageStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:imageData];

[request uploadImageStream:imageStream suggestedFilename:@"Image.jpg" MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"text", @"title", nil]];
```

Comment: put relavent code here :0

Comment: It is sharing, to much code too is there, i added uploading code, but i think the problem is not here.

Comment: Seems to be a token issue from I could see searking in Google "invalid frob flickr".

Comment: Does actually the request go through and get a response? Look at this: [didFailLoadWithError is called with UIWebView even though page later loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028383/didfailloadwitherror-is-called-with-uiwebview-even-though-page-later-loads)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Setup [burpsuite proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/)
2. Point your simulator/mac/iphone to the proxy
3. Turn off SSL on flickr API client. If you cannot turn of SSL for Flickr API, create self signed certificate, import it to iPhone, import it to burpsuite and enable https proxying.
4. Make few requests until you get the error.
5. Inspect error in burpsuite.

Most of this is described in this tutorial: [Intercept iPhone and iPad SSL connections that require a valid SSL certificate](http://community.securusglobal.com/2012/09/11/how-to-intercept-iphone-and-ipad-ssl-connections-that-require-a-valid-ssl-certificate/)

Comment: Is there any tutorial how to make that?

Comment: Try this: http://community.securusglobal.com/2012/09/11/how-to-intercept-iphone-and-ipad-ssl-connections-that-require-a-valid-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Didn't help or i do not understand how to use it

Comment: [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) is easy to set up with the simulator, and they have a certificate ([and instructions](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/)) you can install that will allow it to inspect SSL traffic. It costs money but there is a trial.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time debugging this error:

```
Flickr says: Invalid frob
```

But i am sure that everything is ok with frob string.

I know that it is bad solution, even not a solution, but i made it work: So what i did is after i receive such a rare error I make again token request using the save frob everything works nice. (if frob is really invalid that how can it upload it from the next try).