# Check for NSURLError.Cancelled

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to check if a `NSURLErrorCancelled` occurred. So basically mapping [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028550/426227) to C#.

The only thing I came up with is checking the error code directly:

```
if(e.Error.Code != -999){
    // real error here
}
```

How can I compare the `NSError` with `NSURLError.Cancelled` in case the error code changes sometime?

**Solution linked by [David Karlaš](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661901/david-karla%c5%a1)**:

```
var urlError = default(NSUrlError);
if(!Enum.TryParse<NSUrlError>(e.Error.Code.ToString(), out urlError)){
    urlError = NSUrlError.Unknown;
}
// this is error code -999
if(urlError != NSUrlError.Cancelled){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is way to do it:
[Link to Github code](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/blob/5e795b1f94804a7f0f6955368e15783a083de641/src/ModernHttpClient/iOS/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs#L321-L323)

Also notice that UserCancelledAuthentication is handled same way in switch below... Which you might want to do as well.