# AFNetworking Error Domain Code=-999 ? But works fine?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, networking, afnetworking

I'm getting a strage error from AFNetworking even the though the request seems to work fine (as the change actually happens on the site).

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed 
(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1fd4a080
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://gcm.greenlightdispatch.com/services/json/}
```

The strange thing is that it returns this error but it actually doesn't have a problem completing the request (on the server, the information passes through just fine and all).

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url] autorelease];
[httpClient postPath:@"" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:params]
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Success: %@", [responseObject objectFromJSONData]);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
}];
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in iPhone 3.0 OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been answered many times before. The operation is being canceled which is why you get that error.

[What to do about an NSURLErrorDomain -999?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259899/what-to-do-about-an-nsurlerrordomain-999/7260176#7260176)

Comment: oh ok sry, I wasn't able to find that other post sorry. thanks alot!