# PAYU iOS Non Seamless Integration NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: ios, sdk, payu, nsurlerrordomain

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mobiletest.payu.in/response.php?mihpayid=209ebdca6cb1db2147aaaedecdcb31d4dcc4130714983b608f89eb1b36e103f8&code=14, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mobiletest.payu.in/response.php?mihpayid=209ebdca6cb1db2147aaaedecdcb31d4dcc4130714983b608f89eb1b36e103f8&code=14}
```

I'm getting this error while trying to make a payment using the test credentials provided by Payu. Can anyone please explain what is wrong?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/7260176/2522603

Comment: @shubhsin : Try contacting PayU support .They will support you.

Comment: Had a look at it. Its not that issue. Soomething to do with the SDK. Since I'm not handling that activity

Comment: i also get this type of error ..

Comment: I fixed it. It was sending a different user before. So while setting the attributes, set user_credentials as default