# iOS webViewDidFinishLoading not being called

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and want to display an activity indicator while it is loading. And then hide it when the `webViewDidFinishLoading`. The only problem is that I am getting this `NSURLErrorDomain` error -999 thing going on. After searching around I found [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os) which works to not display any error message but my `webViewDidFinishLoading` doesn't ever get called to get rid of my activity indicator and other stuff that I have going on. I guess I could just make a call to the `didFinishLoading` method in my webViewDidFailWithError method if it fails with -999 but that seems super hacky and wrong. Any ideas on how to fix this?

edit* 
I have figured out where the webview was being asked to load twice so I was able to get rid of the error -999. However, it seems neither of the delegate methods are being called unless I try to load the webview twice (in which case the `webViewDidFinishLoading` method is only called once).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refresh)
                                                 name:@"DidBecomeActive"
                                               object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)refresh{
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myapp.com/app/"]]];
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)wv
{
    NSLog(@"finished loading");
    [self.activityInd stopAnimating];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:wv];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)wv didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error);
    if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled){
        return;
    }
    [self.activityInd stopAnimating];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't find server" message:@"Check your internet connection and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]show];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy/Paste error.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoading:(UIWebView *)wv
```

Should be changed to:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wv
```

Answer (score 13):

Did u assigned the UIWebView delegates to its object like the following

```
webViewObject.delegate = self
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not being called until the second time it tries for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

implemente the protocol "UIWebViewDelegate" in .h file

Answer (score 0):

In case you ended up here because you're wondering why your delegate methods aren't being called when the bug wasn't due to an incorrectly written delegate method:

Say your webview is normally instantiated via Interface Builder, but you forget to hook it up correctly (meaning it isn't instantiated). You can still set its delegate (e.g., `self.webview.delegate = self;`) without crashing or exceptions (provided `self` conforms to the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol).

Similarly, you can load HTML into it (e.g., `[self.webview loadHTMLString:someHTMLString baseURL:nil];`) and the app will continue along happily without complaints. This would take you to an awkward situation where you've set the delegate, written the delegate methods correctly, loaded something into the webview, but your delegate methods will never fire.

So the advice for that situation: make sure you double check that your webview is connected properly (to the correct instance property/variable) in Interface Builder.