# iOS7 UIWebView wont load page, but it loads on iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, webview, ios7

I have an app with multiple webViews, on iOS6 it loads perfectly (sometimes I have to manually refresh the webviews content, and it works fine), but on iOS7 (the same code, the same sdk-ios7sdk) the webViews loads the first time, then if i hit refresh i get -999 error code, if i navigate to a page, then refresh the webviews data, then go back to view the webview, it works...

Here's the error message:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x9ba3220 
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/jakaba/Library/Application%20Support/
iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/.../myapp.app/page.html, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/jakaba/Library/Application%20Support/
iPhone%20Simulator/7.0/Applications/.../myapp.app/page.html}
```

Any idea?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at this question:

[How do I fix NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in iPhone 3.0 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os)

The error code you're seeing is caused by two simultaneous requests on the `UIWebView`. This can be caused by a couple of things. Is your HTML doing any redirects? How are you loading the content into the `UIWebView`?

Anyway, take a look at the question I've linked to and see if it helps you. As to why you're seeing this on iOS 7 and not 6 - WebKit is improved in 7, and you may be encountering a race condition you didn't before due to speed.

Comment: It's possible that two simultaneous requests are sent to the `UIWebView`, thank you for the idea, i'll look at it :)

Comment: I cant get it working, could you please help me with the debugging?

Comment: I found the problem! I use notifications in my app, and accidentally i left a postNotificationName in the code, so my listener is called twice :D Thank you for your help!