# (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have found this error:

> Error - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999
>
> The operation couldn’t be completed. `(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)`

During load youtube link on my `UIWebView` first time.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: check this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os).. It may help you..

Comment: do u have the solution or not yet @Tarang ?

Answer (score 5):

-999 error code means NSURLErrorCancelled.
This happens when the past request is cancelled.
If it works without any issues except that, no problem :)

See: [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: so what it is the solution ? when user kill the app the request is cancelled. so what i can do ?

Comment: This error, crashing my app, please let me provide a solution.