# Strange Behaviour while loading URL in Webview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

It looks simple, but don't know what goes wrong. I am trying to load a basic URL in `WebView`, as shown below

```
 WebsiteWebView.delegate=self;
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://firstclasspizzaoc.com/"];
 [WebsiteWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

while loading i am getting below error everytime..

```
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0xe036d20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://firstclasspizzaoc.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://firstclasspizzaoc.com/}
2014-01-07 15:18:46.142 FirstClassPizza[1583:

Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0xe0ef310 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=XXXXXXXX, NSErrorFailingURLKey=XXXXXXXX, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0xcbe9130 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}
```

At Browser it is loading perfectly..

Please suggest what went wrong in my code..

Any Valuable suggestions will be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: I would say that there's a problem with an internet connection

Comment: Internet connection is working fine...Other URL's are loading...

Comment: are you connected to any firewall, proxy etc that might be blocking it? also try adding www. just incase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 It is due to Your Web URL http://firstclasspizzaoc.com/ can you use your url with
http://www.firstclasspizzaoc.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here :

[How do I fix NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in iPhone 3.0 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os)

This thread contained this description for this error:          "This error may occur if an another request is made before the previous request of WebView is completed..."

I worked around this by ignoring this error and letting the webview continue to load.

```
   if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) {

     //show error alert, etc.
    }
```