# UIWebView error -999

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a UIWebView just on a View and when I cliked in a link, I launch this view with a good content.

```
NSLog(@"---> %@",url);

NSURL *websiteUrlL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *urlRequestT = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrlL];

NSLog(@"---> %@",urlRequestT);
```

In my Output I have

- url : is good with http:// URL .php
- urlRequestT : is good with :  { URL: http:// URL .php }

> ```
> (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
> {
>     NSLog(@"Error %li", (long)error.code);
>     if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) return; // this is Error -999
>         NSLog(@"Canceled request: %@", [webView.request.URL absoluteString]);
> }
> ```

In my Output Error I have the number -999

I don't know why my page doesn't load with this type of file...
My UiWebView works fine with a simple html file
Thanks for advance.

I finished to find the good answer, the better place for load content in UIWebView is in viewDidAppear not in viewDidLoad

Comment: What is the ending of your last sentence ("I don't")?  And if the error is "`NSURLErrorCancelled`", might this be the server that's telling the requesting process (i.e. your app) that the loading has been cancelled?

Comment: When I search this site for 'NSURLErrorCancelled', I get 67 answers.  Do any of them apply to your situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os follow this link

Comment: @PhillipMills Nothing resolve my issue, that why I create this post...

Answer (score 0):

i think you are having escape sequences in url 
try loading webview with this

```
url  = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *websiteUrlL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *urlRequestT = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrlL];
NSLog(@"---> %@",urlRequestT);
```

Comment: I have the same error